# Weird output voltage from smps

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, h-bridge, bridge-rectifier

I just completed a half bridge smps and had a test run.
The series bulb on input just blink for a second at first and then shut down at it should.
But the output voltage is quite weird because my multimeter is reading about 0.5,3,7,11,7,5,... Volts changing constantly and when I shut it down, the voltage is 27volts in the capacitors.
I have not connected any till now.

[image]

Is my multimeter incorrect because I am using a very cheap multimeter? A change I did in the circuit is that I used a full bridge rectifier 35A for output rather than dual-diodes because I don't have any. Can that be a problem too? Also the voltage I calculated for secondary was between 38-40 volts but I am getting 27 volts after shutdown.
Thank you

Comment: Check the reverse recovery specification for the (normally really crappy) bridge rectifier verses the (normally quite fast with low reverse recovery time) diodes originally specified. Don't just change stuff because you didn't have stuff. Would you put a tractor wheel on a scooter because you had a puncture and couldn't mend it?

Comment: _" multimeter is reading about 0.5,3,7,11,7,5,... Volts"_ You can't develop an SMPS without an oscilloscope. An oscilloscope by itself will not fix your problem here, but won't allow you do diagnose the problem either. Also, you have a long trail of unanswered questions here on EE.SE.

Comment: "In the capacitors" Which capacitors?